# PostgreSQL apply filter only if column exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I am building an application which will construct SQL query (in Postgres) and apply some filtering to it. The problem is, once the filter is selected in the app, all the queries are receiving it, and sometimes we use tables which do have columns used in a filter.

Is there a way to skip filter if the column does not exist?

In pseudocode something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE [if col exists] col > 1;
```

I was not able to find anything like that, but maybe there are some tricks.

Comment: This requirement probably indicates a design problem, because once you are at the point where you need to query, you usually already have full knowledge/expectation of the table structure.

Comment: You need code that dynamically creates a valid piece of SQL. You could do it in a SQL function, but I also think that you have a much larger design problem. Fix that problem first, before you start looking for work arounds.

Comment: It's probably possible with some ugly JSON casting, but performance will be quite bad

Comment: Thanks guys for suggestions, I will try to solve this on application level.